# HTML5 PHP form won't send

Tags: php, forms, html

I have adapted new fields from a previous form build that worked fine. The client side validation works fine but their seems to be a php issue as the email does not send.

I am still learning PHP and forms so any help would be ace!

Please the relevant code form the from page and the php below;

The Page

```
    <div id="contact-form" class="clearfix">
        <h1>SWPEE certificate</h1><br>
        <?php
        //init variables
        $cf = array();
        $sr = false;

        if(isset($_SESSION['cf_returndata'])){
            $cf = $_SESSION['cf_returndata'];
            $sr = true;
        }
        ?>
        <ul id="errors" class="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">
            <li id="info">There were some problems with your form submission:</li>
            <?php 
            if(isset($cf['errors']) && count($cf['errors']) > 0) :
                foreach($cf['errors'] as $error) :
            ?>
            <li><?php echo $error ?></li>
            <?php
                endforeach;
            endif;
            ?>
        </ul>
        <p id="success" class="<?php echo ($sr && $cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">Thanks you. Your information has been submitted.</p>
        <form method="post" action="process2.php">
            <label for="firstname">First Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="first name" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['first name'] : '' ?>" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus />

            <label for="surname">Surname: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['surname'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Surname" required autofocus />

            <label for="jobtitle">Job title: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="jobtitle" name="job title" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['job title'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Job title" required autofocus />

            <label for="office">Office location:</label>
            <select id="office" name="office">
                <option value="Birmingham" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['office'] == 'Birmingham') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Birmingham</option>
                <option value="Chippenham" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['office'] == 'Chippenham') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Chippenham</option>
                <option value="Croyden" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['office'] == 'Croyden') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Croyden</option>
                <option value="Glasgow" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['office'] == 'Glasgow') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Glasgow</option>
                <option value="Hornsey" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['office'] == 'Hornsey') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Hornsey</option>
                <option value="London" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['office'] == 'London') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>London</option>
                <option value="Swanley" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['office'] == 'Swanley') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Swanley</option>
                <option value="York" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['office'] == 'York') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>York</option>
            </select>

            <label for="emp_con">Employee or Contractor:</label>
            <select id="emp_con" name="emp_con">
            <option value="Employee" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['cmp_con'] == 'Employee') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Employee</option>
                <option value="Contractor" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['cmp_con'] == 'Contractor') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Contractor</option>
            </select>

            <label for="course_module">Course or Module: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="course_module" name="course module" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['course module'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Course or Module name" required autofocus />

            <label for="date">Date Course or Module was completed: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="date_completed" name="date completed" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['date completed'] : '' ?>" placeholder="23/7/2012" required autofocus />

            <label for="line_manager">Line Manager: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="line_manager" name="line manager" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['line manager'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Line Manager" required autofocus />

            <span id="loading"></span>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" />
            <p id="req-field-desc"><span class="required">*</span> indicates a required field</p>
        </form>
        <?php unset($_SESSION['cf_returndata']); ?>
    </div>
```

The Processor (process2.php) I have a dummy email address in here its not just a typo!

```
//form validation vars
$formok = true;
$errors = array();

//sumbission data
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date('d/m/Y');
$time = date('H:i:s');

//form data
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$job_title = $_POST['job_title'];
$office = $_POST['office'];
$emp_con = $_POST['emp_con'];
$course_module = $_POST['course_module'];
$date_completed = $_POST['date_completed'];
$line_manager = $_POST['line_manager'];

//validate form data

//validate name is not empty
if(empty($first_name)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered your first name";
}

if(empty($surename)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered your surname";
}

if(empty($job_title)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a job title";
}

if(empty($course_module)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a course module";
}

if(empty($line_manager)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered the name of your line manager";
}

if(empty($date_completed)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered the date you completed your module";
}

//send email if all is ok
if($formok){
    $headers = "From: website@invensysgrad.com" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $emailbody = "<p>You have received a new message from the enquiries form on your website.</p>
                  <p><strong>First Name: </strong> {$first_name} </p>
                  <p><strong>Surname: </strong> {$surname} </p>
                  <p><strong>Job title: </strong> {$job_title} </p>
                  <p><strong>Office: </strong> {$office} </p>
                  <p><strong>Employee or Contractor: </strong> {$emp_con} </p>
                  <p><strong>Course or Module title: </strong> {$course_module} </p>
                  <p><strong>Date Course or Module was completed: </strong> {$date_completed} </p>
                  <p>This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</p>";

    mail("myemail@address.com","SWPEE Certificate form",$emailbody,$headers);

}

//what we need to return back to our form
$returndata = array(
    'posted_form_data' => array(
        'first_name' => $first_name,
        'surname' => $surname,
        'job_title' => $job_title,
        'office' => $office,
        'emp_con' => $emp_con,
        'course_module' => $course_module,
        'date_completed' => $date_completed,
        'line_manager' => $line_manager
    ),
    'form_ok' => $formok,
    'errors' => $errors
);


//if this is not an ajax request
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){
    //set session variables
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;

    //redirect back to form
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

}

Comment: When you say that it doesn't send... What _does_ it do?  If you debug the code, at what point does it deviate from expected behavior?  Does it even get to the line which sends the email?  If not, why not?  In what way does it fail?

Comment: try debug php: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: does formok==true at the right point?

Comment: Its returns the error message for the surname field. Even when this correct, and the jQuery validates it fine. This stops the form from posting. So new to this its all a bit big and scary!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($surename)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered your surname";
}
```

Try change $surename to $surname

```
if(empty($surname)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered your surname";
}
```

Edit: Wow didn't see how long ago this was posted sorry was just related to my question so had a quick look and noticed an error.